# This mysql_query just work some times

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know why but this mysql_query is just working some times. i don't know why becasue everything is working fine
this one here:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `profit`=profit+$profit, `won`=won+$jackpotcost, `gameswon`=gameswon+1, `games`=games+1 WHERE `steamid`='$winnerid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

But this one does not work:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    if($row["userid"] == $winnerid)
    {
        $time=time();
        $time=$time+10;
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `profit`=profit+$profit, `won`=won+$jackpotcost, `gameswon`=gameswon+1, `games`=games+1 WHERE `steamid`='$winnerid'") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (`type`,`app`,`userid`,`title`,`msg`,`time`,`active`,`delay`) VALUES ('success','0','$winnerid','Congratulations!','You won $$jackpotcost in Game #$cg with a $wonpercent% chance!','10',1,$time)");
    }
    else
    {
        $loserid = $row["userid"];
        $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$p2t."game".$cg." WHERE `userid`=".$loserid."");
        $losercost=0;
        while($lrow = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            $losercost+=$lrow['value'];

        }
        $time=time();
        $time=$time+10;
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `profit`=profit-$losercost, `games`=games+1 WHERE `steamid`='$loserid'") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (`type`,`app`,`userid`,`title`,`msg`,`time`,`active`,`delay`) VALUES ('error','0','$loserid','GL Next Game!','$winnername won $$jackpotcost in Game #$cg with a $wonpercent% chance!','10',1,$time)");

    }
}
```

If someone can help me and explain what is wrong with it

Comment: So which query exactly is causing the issue?   **Side Note:** mysql_* functions are deprecated, so you should use mysqli_* functions or PDO.

Comment: If you upgrade to the current version of PHP, it won't work at all. Those `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for 5 years, and they're gone completely now. Alternatives like PDO have been available for more than 10 years, you should be working with that instead.

Comment: @miken32 I don't think that first query is part of the same script. It's something he said is working OK by comparison.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting the `$rs` variable on the inner loop. Change the name and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working sometimes, I suspect that you are not using `mysql_real_escape_string($variable)`.

You'll want to do:

```
$variable = ""; // content goes here

// then for readying the input
mysql_real_escape($variable);
$query = ""; // your query goes here.
mysql_query($query);
```

## What does this do?

---

`mysql_real_escape_string()` Is going to escape quotes that are entered into the variable or user input.
It will ready your varable/input for queries.

**NOTE:** You might want to move to `MySQLi` (AKA: `MySQL improved`) or move to PDO. It will improve your code majorly with security issues.

Hoped this helped.